# SSD Trim and file slack space

Tags: ssd, trim, slack

Does Trim work in the background to tell the SSD to delete slack space of files that get smaller or larger or get overwritten by smaller files?

Can remnants of say an audio or video file or picture be partially recovered from an SSD's file slack space when Trim command is in operation after about 1 week has gone by?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Does Trim work in the background to tell the SSD to delete slack space of files that get smaller or larger or get overwritten by smaller files?

It can work that way. Whether it actually does depends on the OS and the way trim is configured.

> Can remnants of say an audio or video file or picture be partially recovered from an SSD's file slack space when Trim command is in operation after about 1 week has gone by?

Unlikely, since the slack space is erased by the SSD as soon as it has spare I/O capacity. That's pretty much the point of trimming it -- to allow it to be erased before needed. It's much more likely to be recoverable without trim since the filesystem may not overwrite it for a long time.